# Limit statement in PartiQL - Get Last row

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-qldb, partiql

How do I use Limit in PartiQL?
What I need is the last 3 rows from the table of Amazon QLDB which uses PartiQL Syntax for querying.
Something like
**SELECT * FROM Accounts where AddedBy = 'admin@demo.com' LIMIT 3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIMIT` isn't currently supported by Amazon QLDB. Here's a more detailed answer to your question [Pagination in QLDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59502337/pagination-in-qldb).

Answer (score 1):

`Limit` is now supported in the `ExecuteStatement` command. See the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ExecuteStatement.html#API_ExecuteStatement_RequestSyntax) for sending it as part of the request.

Here is the [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/03/amazon-dynamodb-limit-request-partiql-operations/) from March 8, 2022.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same issue I faced. So I write a project to extend PartiQL capbilities. Please refer here: https://github.com/passren/PyDynamoDB

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT works differently than I thought it would. LIMIT means you want to limit your search to that number of rows. So LIMIT=10 means you are only going to query a maximum of 10 rows.

And it does not go in the statement string, but instead in the method call. For example:

```
import boto3

stmt = "SELECT * FROM \"my-table\" WHERE my_key = \'some_key\'"
dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')
resp = dynamodb.execute_statement(Statement=stmt, Limit=10)
print(resp['Items'])
```

Here is the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ExecuteStatement.html#API_ExecuteStatement_RequestSyntax